# Is thesis's project correct?

Tags: apostrophe

This is a general question I had in years. When we want to declare possession, we use the apostrophe and the s.

For example: Bayern's best goalkeeper is Oliver Kahn.

What about the words that end with an s though? If I put the trailing s there, it doesn't sound nice to me.

---

If you have a better title in mind, please let me know.

Comment: Your general question is answered in the link in the previous comment. In re: your specific question, there's nothing orthographically or grammatically wrong with *thesis's project*, but there's something conceptually off: theses typically don't have projects (they have *aims* or *premises* or whatever).

Comment: @DanBron thanks for the link. I just read the answer there, should I mark it as duplicate or delete the question? In my field, the good ones (should) have. So, I should right thesis's project and it's pronounced "thesises project"?

Comment: Yes, we'll close it as a dupe. And yep, it's pronounced *thesis-iz project*.